# Select In PostgreSQL Table Inheritance

Tags: postgresql, inheritance, partitioning

I have main table product, it has subtables product_store_1, ... , product_store_N based on store_id field. Product table has rules, they insert new row to one of subtables depends on store_id. It seems to work fine, but main table currently is not empty and I want to get which rule is missed. I'm trying to

```
SELECT store_id,count(*) FROM product GROUP BY store_id;
```

But it runs for all product_store_N tables, I want to run this query only for parent table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use *ONLY* in *FROM* clause

```
SELECT store_id,count(*) 
FROM ONLY product 
GROUP BY store_id;
```

---

see this example :

```
CREATE TABLE parent (value INT);
CREATE TABLE child_a () INHERITS (parent);
CREATE TABLE child_n() INHERITS (parent);

INSERT INTO parent VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3),(4);
INSERT INTO child_a VALUES (10),(20),(30),(40),(5);
INSERT INTO child_n VALUES (50),(60),(70),(80),(6);
```

if I query `select * from  parent where value <10` the result will be

```
   Value
   -----
    0
    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
    6
```

the last two `rows` that's `5` and `6` belongs to `child_a` and  `child_n` respectively.

To get Value in `Parent` table use `ONLY` in `FROM` clause. i.e:

`SELECT * FROM  ONLY PARENT WHERE value <10`

```
   Value
   -----
    0
    1
    2
    3
    4
```

[**sqlfiddle-demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/84080/3/0)